# How robotized chats are made?

Tags: chatbot, hubot, chatops

I find some websites, which provides: "Lawyer robot" where you can ask questions, and fill dome forms. I want to ask how they ate made?

Is there are usually used some chatbots or chatops engines, (as example: HUBOT)?

Also is it possible to make such, which can communicate in different than English language? Haven't find any information about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chatbots are a trend right now and they can be made with different technologies like HUBOT as you stated or from scratch with any programming language you would like. But the bots made this way will mostly handle the initial steps like connecting to specific channels like Slack, FB Messenger and IRC, receiving some messages and executing some scripts or commands based on some logic.

The real magic that makes the robots *think* and really understand languages requires computational power and  a big amount of data to learn from. Enter the ***cloud bot platforms*** (I just made up this name). They are AI cloud platforms using Machine Learning specialized on language recognition, conversation, natural language, speech to text, tone analyzer, visual recognition, etc, that makes your bot smarter, able to handle much more than the initial get some commands from the chat and execute some scripts.

Some that I know of are:

- [IBM Watson](https://www.ibm.com/watson)
- [Motion.ai](https://www.motion.ai/): Still in beta.
- [Api.ai](https://api.ai/)

All of them are paid but offer a free plan so you can get started.

I believe that IBM Watson has is the most developed by now, having many different features including translation for English to Arabic, French, Portuguese for Spanish most of them.

If you want to get started I would suggest the following two articles. I've tried them myself and it's understand and dream about the possibilities:

- [How to build a Facebook Messenger Chatbot in 10 minutes](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-build-a-facebook-messenger-chatbot-in-10-mi-1)
- [Build a chat bot in ten minutes with Watson](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/watson/2016/12/build-chat-bot/)

Also take a look at these sample applications made with Watson:

- [Enhanced Conversation Demo](http://conversation-enhanced.mybluemix.net/?cm_mc_uid=31094982291214821489022&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1482148902)
- [Cognitive car demo](https://conversation-demo.mybluemix.net/?cm_mc_uid=31094982291214821489022&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1482148902)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and useful links.
What about custom conversation languages? How best way to make robot speak other languages, than English? For example Italian

Comment: You could receive the messages in Italian, translate it to English using Watson Language Translator, pass it on so the bot can answer it, translate the answer back to Italian and send it to the requester. You will need to do it until the resource you are looking for has support to Italian. This is a link of a demo app using the Translator API: https://language-translator-demo.mybluemix.net/?cm_mc_uid=31094982291214821489022&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1482162975

Comment: Thank you one more time, for advice.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently embarked on this learning curve:

I'm currently looking at the following two platforms:

1. [Motion AI](https://www.motion.ai/)
2. [API.AI](https://api.ai/) - Owned by google, and very easy to use.

I'm not sure about different languages as I've only built for English, but check out their documentation.